# quicks books online how to refresh token to authenticate. with python

Tags: python, authentication, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

This is my code:

```py
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient  # intuit library
from quickbooks import QuickBooks  # python-quickbooks package

# auth credentials to connect to the QBO account
auth_client = AuthClient(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    environment=ENV,
    redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
)

# directoryPath = parameters.directoryPath

# creating the client object to access the QBO account - if not able to connect, make 3 tries dans then stop
tries = 3
for i in range(tries):
    try:
        client = QuickBooks(
            auth_client=auth_client,
            refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN,
            company_id=COMPANY_ID,
        )

        # get the refresh token returned
        refresh_token_new = client.auth_client.refresh_token

        # if the refresh token has changed, update it in the csv
        if REFRESH_TOKEN != refresh_token_new:
            print('Updating the refresh token. ' + REFRESH_TOKEN + ' --> ' + refresh_token_new)
            # fieldnames list required for DictWriter
            fieldnames = ['client_id', 'client_secret', 'company_id', 'refresh_token', 'env']
            tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)
            with open('../meta.csv') as csvfile, tempfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
                writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                values = next(reader)
                values['refresh_token'] = refresh_token_new
                writer.writerow(values)
                # saving the contents of temp file into the main file
                shutil.move(tempfile.name, '../meta.csv')
```

It works if my `refresh_token` is valid but when renewing it, it seems that it lose it....
My object is naturally refresh token in order to access to QBO automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see from where you get REFRESH_TOKEN and how do you save it between calls. Maybe there is a reason why it gets lost.

Also, QuickBooks class will not refresh the token automatically. You need to do that explicitly in your code/app.